# Examples of badly behaved derivatives

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Consider a real valued function $g$ on an open interval $(a,b)$ which is the derivative of a function continuous on $[a,b]$ at each point of $(a,b)$. The function $g$ has the intermediate value property, so a monotone $g$ will have to be continuous, a general $g$ cannot have simple discontinuities, etc. With such constraints how badly can a derivative behave in terms of continuity, can it get much worse than the derivative of say, $x^2 \sin(1/x)
$?

Comment: May be it is possible to find a relevant answer in a classical book:
Bernard R. Gelbaum, John M. H. Olmsted: Counterexamples in Analysis.

Comment: The $x^2 \sin(1/x)$ example is taken from that book. If I recall correctly, they don't have many examples on discontinuous derivatives.

Comment: I don't know whether there will be examples that satisfy you there,
but my favoured source for wacky real functions is van Rooij and
Schikhof's A Second Course in Real Functions:
http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Cqk5AAAAIAAJ&lpg=PP1&dq=schikhof&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false .

Comment: Thanks a lot, the section on derivatives looks interesting.

Comment: Are you asking about $g$ or $g'$?

Comment: I mean $g = f'$  for some $f$.

Comment: This question was bumped up to the "front page" due to some edits, and since it appears no questions are linked to it (surprisingly; there are a lot of good answers here), it might be a good idea to cite (and thereby link) an answer I recently wrote to [Regularity of lipschitz and derivable function](https://mathoverflow.net/q/430347/15780) that describes the strongest results I know.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Talking about how bad may be the derivative of an everywhere derivable function on the interval $[a,b]$, the natural example that occurs to my mind is: a Pompeiu derivative, that is, a derivative that vanishes in a dense set (these weird functions, however, constitue a closed linear space of $C^0[a,b]$, while it's not even obvious that they are closed wrto addition!). For an account on the subject you may refer e.g. to the above quoted book by Andrew M. Bruckner [*Differentiation of real functions*](https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0069821): it's also in the CRM series now (here is a preview:
[Google Books](http://books.google.it/books?id=fXfEG-F2zJUC)).

For a quick reference, you may also have a look to the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeiu_derivative) (it's me who wrote it ;-) ).

Comment: Do we know also if it has zero derivative almost everywhere?

Comment: This derivative $f'$ is also bounded, so $f$  is Lipschitz, and if $f'$ was $0$ a.e., $f$ would be constant

Answer (score 21):

Of course every continuous function is a derivative, so your question seems like it could be reinterpreted as the *characterization problem for derivatives*: that is, give "nice" necessary and sufficient conditions on a function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for it to be the derivative of some other function (one-sided, at the endpoints).

As others have pointed out, any derivative must be a **Darboux function** -- i.e., satisfy the conclusion of the Intermediate Value Theorem -- and also a **Baire class one function** -- i.e., a pointwise limit of continuous functions.  The latter implies that the set of discontinuities is meager.  A lot of work has been done seeking to understand "how much bigger" the class of Darboux, Baire Class 1 functions is than the class of derivatives.

Here are some references:

> Bruckner, A. M.; Leonard, J. L. *Derivatives*. Amer. Math. Monthly 73 1966 no. 4, part II, 24--56.

[http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/BrucknerLeonard66.pdf](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/BrucknerLeonard66.pdf) or http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/andy1966.pdf

> Bruckner, Andrew M. Differentiation of real functions. Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 659. Springer, Berlin, 1978. x+247 pp.

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183545222

> Bruckner, Andrew M.
> The problem of characterizing derivatives revisited.
> Real Anal. Exchange 21 (1995/96), no. 1, 112--133.

https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rae/1341343228

Comment: +1! Apart the very good quality of this answer, I need to pull it up since I referred to it as being "above"

Comment: This is a revelation, I didn't realize this was such a deep subject.

Comment: Since neither http://www.math.uga.edu/~pete/BrucknerLeonard66.pdf nor http://math.uga.edu/~pete/BrucknerLeonard66.pdf work, I have added a link to the copy of that paper [on the author's homepage](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/andy1966.pdf), People who do not mind paywalls can also try https://www.jstor.org/stable/2313749 or https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1966.11970916

Comment: @Martin: I'm having some technical issues right now, but I should be able to fix the links tomorrow.

Answer (score 13):

Derivatives are like continuous functions in that both have the intermediate value property, but they need not have the extreme value property.  Gelbaum and Olmstead, *Counterexamples in Analysis*, gives as [example 3.7](https://books.google.com/books?id=0ZYoAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA37) the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x^4 e^{-\frac{1}{4}x^2}\sin\frac{8}{x^3}, & x \ne 0 \\ 0, & x=0 \end{cases}
$$
for which $f'$ exists everywhere, but does not achieve its supremum on the compact interval $[-1,1]$.

On the other hand, a derivative cannot have too many discontinuities.  Lars Olsen at  [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160912181742/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=281579&tstart=0) points out that a derivative is a pointwise limit of the continuous functions and hence of Baire class at most 1, and therefore its set of discontinuities is meager (in particular, has dense complement).

Answer (score 7):

I think it can.  In particular, Wikipedia's [*antiderivative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative#Of_non-continuous_functions) ([current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Antiderivative&oldid=849583931#Of_non-continuous_functions)) page seems to imply that, for any meagre $F_\sigma$ subset of an open interval, one can construct a function whose derivative is discontinuous on that subset.  It also gives some examples.

Answer (score 6):

In Y. Katznelson and K. Stromberg’s paper “Everywhere differentiable, nowhere
monotone, functions,” *Amer. Math. Monthly* **81** (1974), no. 4, 349–354 (doi: [10.1080/00029890.1974.11993558](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.1974.11993558), [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2318996)), there is a construction, based on somewhat similar ideas to those described in Majer’s above mentioned article, whereby for any two disjoint countable sets $A, B \subset \mathbb{R}$ there exists a differentiable function whose derivative equals $1$ on $A$ and is less than $1$ on $B$.   So if $A$ and $B$ are both dense in $\mathbb{R}$ then this derivative must be discontinuous at every point of $B$.